# Static IP on a network

Tags: networking, ip, router

I want to maintain one computer on a network with a static IP. I have no access to the router, so I cannot reserve the address there.

My question is; if I do this, is it possible the router will assign the same IP address to another computer?

lee

Comment: Yes, it's possible that DHCP server will assign that IP address to some other machine (depending on the IP range it's managing). You didn't specify *why* you want static address though.

Comment: It depends, There usually is a threshold over which values are assigned, if you can find out the lowest existing IPAddress you can try assigning a number less than that. But if you do assign an address in that range that the router is assigning, then yes the router can assign a duplicate

Comment: I want to write an application to be used by schools on their networks. However, the users are often not computer literate and I so I want to make setting-up the app as simple as possilbe. I cannot guarantee someone at the school would know how to reserve IP addresses.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to set up a server with an arbitrary IP address on an intranet, and then give that address to people so they can point their browsers to it? If that's correct, is there a specific you cannot host your app on the internet?

Comment: *Why* is your application concerned with IP allocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a server to always have the same address.  I think that is too low level.  Why not just require a specific computer name, such as `myapp-server`.  Then the school could either name the server `myapp-server` or just do DNS translation; either by creating an ALIAS record in there DNS server or by changing the LMHOSTS file on each client.

I've used `DNS mapping` in many production environments.  It makes life really simple for the developers and the system admins.  Every admin will know how to add a DNS host name to their network.  And worst case, if no real network admin you can always hardwire IP addresss in LMHOSTS files.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting idea. How would you call something like that from a remote access? For example, if I wanted to make an HTTP call, would it be 'http://myapp-server'? This is assuming we used choice 1 'Then the school could either name the servicer myapp-server '.

Comment: Yes, thats the whole idea.  The URL would always be `http://myapp-server/...`.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I will experiment with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can always instruct the app to used DHCP with manual. But as long as that IP address is part of a DHCP pool there is always the edge-case risk that someone else could grab it if—let’s say—the server goes down, machines on the network start before the server is rebooted & bye, bye network.

But maybe instead of the IP address being static you should investigate using a multicast setup similar to [Avahi](http://avahi.org) (an open source version of [Apple’s Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/)) to setup `zeroconf` networking.

That way your app can have a unique broadcast hostname & the IP issue is a non-issue. The IP could change all the time for all it matters because the whole concept of Avahi is to simply give a common alias to changing IPs.

Using the example of `myapp-server` as outlined in another answer, you just need to setup Avahi on the machine you plan to have the app on and then you can access it via `http://myapp-server.local` and the beauty of it is you never have to mess with routers or DNS entries.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However, I am hoping to create a set-up that can be done by people who are not necessarily computer savvy. This approach seems like it could become complicated for them.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I went and read about both of them after you mentioned it. For this project, it will probably be a .NET app. But more importantly, I need to create a solution that, for the most part, the final user can just install the app, do a few very minor settings and GO. - Thanks again for responding. I just looked and saw there are .NET wrappers for Bonjour. I will look at them, but I think maybe setting the computer name will work for my needs.

Comment: Thanks again. I just found this: http://craz.net/programs/ZeroconfNetServices/ - Looks like it could do the trick.